# ArcGIS Near tool returning incorrect results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, proximity

I'm having some odd issues with the Near tool in ArcMap 10.4.1 using Geodesic method, no location or angle specified. The tool works, but returns near FIDs for polygons that are absolutely not the nearest. For instance, I can visually see that polygons from the input feature and near feature are adjacent, but the NEAR_FID is for a different polygon.

I've repaired geometry on all involved parties, converted multi-part to single-part for the near features, and tried a variety of search radius sizes.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What inputs did you use in the Near tool?

Comment: Both inputs are shapefiles.

Comment: Sorry I mean what values did you use for each parameter in the tool dialog

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add this info

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I edited based on what I think you're asking for, I don't remember what radius sizes I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this before, I think it was a bug (although I thought it had been fixed by 10.4, so might be different).

What we had to do was this:

1. Select by Location, using the desired search radius
2. Then run Near tool without a search radius.

The NEAR tool would run only on the selected records (from the Select by Location) and have the same effect as doing a Near search with a radius.